# Why is axios being called twice in my program

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to set profile state through redux. However for some reason my axios is being called twice

my database profile.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users"
  },
  preference: [
    {
      type: String
    }
  ],

  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model("profile", ProfileSchema);
```

myCreatePreferences class

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import checkboxes from "./checkboxes";
import Checkbox from "./Checkbox";
import axios from "axios";
import { Redirect } from "react-router";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Select from "react-select";
import { getCurrentProfile } from "../../actions/profileActions";
const options = [
  { value: "Guns", label: "Guns" },
  { value: "Gay Marriage", label: "Gay Marriage" },
  { value: "Abortion", label: "Abortion" },
  { value: "IT", label: "IT" }
];

class CreatePreferences extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedOption: [],
      fireRedirect: false
    };
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let tempArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.selectedOption.length; i++) {
      tempArray[i] = this.state.selectedOption[i].value;
    }
    const preference = {
      tempArray
    };
    //axios
    // .post("/api/profile/", { tempArray: tempArray })
    //.then(res => res.data)
    // .catch(err => console.log(err));
    this.props.getCurrentProfile(preference);
    this.setState({ fireRedirect: true });
  }

  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    console.log(selectedOption.value);
    const { fireRedirect } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <Select
            value={selectedOption}
            isMulti
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            options={options}
          />
          <input
            type="submit"
            className="btn btn-info btn-block mt-4"
            value="Save Preferences"
          />
          {fireRedirect && <Redirect to={"/"} />}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
CreatePreferences.propTypes = {
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  profile: state.profile
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getCurrentProfile }
)(withRouter(CreatePreferences));
```

my profileActionsclass

```
import axios from "axios";

import {
  GET_PROFILE,
  PROFILE_LOADING,
  GET_ERRORS,
  CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE
} from "./types";

//Get current profile

export const getCurrentProfile = preference => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setProfileLoading());
  axios
    .post("/api/profile", preference)
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_PROFILE,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_PROFILE,
        payload: { err }
      })
    );
};

//Profile Loading

export const setProfileLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: PROFILE_LOADING
  };
};
//Clear Profile
export const clearCurrentProfile = () => {
  return {
    type: CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE
  };
};
```

profileReducer.js

```
import {
  GET_PROFILE,
  PROFILE_LOADING,
  CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE
} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  profile: null,
  profiles: null,
  loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PROFILE_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case GET_PROFILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: null
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The index.js class redux store.

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import authReducer from "./authReducer";
import errorReducer from "./errorReducer";
import profileReducer from "./profileReducer";
import postReducer from "./postReducer";
export default combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  errors: errorReducer,
  profile: profileReducer,
  post: postReducer
});
```

When I posting data from the createPreference class via the profileActions through axios I am getting two axios post request. It first fills the preference as expected, however it makes another call instantly and the preference is again set to null.The console.log(of the call)

```
preference: Array(2), _id: "5bbc73011f67820748fcd9ab", user: "5bb87db33cb39a844f0ea46a", date: "2018-10-09T09:21:05.968Z", __v: 0}
Dashboard.js:20 {preference: null, _id: "5bbc73011f67820748fcd9ab", user: "5bb87db33cb39a844f0ea46a", date: "2018-10-09T09:21:05.968Z", __v: 0}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Because you are calling it in the `onSubmit` Methode and it the `getCurrentProfile` function

Comment: @evgenifotia I think it is being called once. Can you explain where are the two calls, so I can correct it.Thanks

Comment: I want to be sure of something first. can you do `console.log("1111")` after `export const getCurrentProfile = preference => dispatch => {` in `my profileActionsclass`

Answer (score 4):

Since I don't have access to your all of your code (and can't debug it), here's a better approach to fetching data. I've structured it closely to what you have and if you follow the working example, you should be able to eliminate the problem.

What I did:

1. Renamed `onSubmit={this.onSubmit}` to a more standard declarative `this.handleSubmit` method
2. Called `this.setState()` in the `handleSubmit` class method to remove `selectedOption` value, then in the setState callback, called `getCurrentProfile(value, history)` (substitute the `value` with your `tempArray`)
3. Changed your `<input type="submit" ... />` to a `<button type="submit" ... />`
4. Added a `return` for the `axios.get(...)` call (I've also included an `async/await` version of `getCurrentProfile` which might be easier to understand -- also substitute the `axios.get` call for your `axios.post` call)
5. Removed `Redirect` and instead placed a redirect inside the `action` creator as `history.push('/');` (once request has been successfully sent, it'll redirect the user back to "/" -- if error, no redirect)
6. Always keep your redux state as a 1:1. In other words, if it's an array, then it stays an array (**not** `null`), if it's a string, it stays a string (**not** `number`)...etc. When using `PropTypes,` your app will throw errors if you do not keep this 1:1 pattern. For example, you're initially setting `profile: null`, but then you set it as `profile: [ Object, Object, Object ... ]`. Instead, it should initially be: `profile: []`.
7. When using `PropTypes`, avoid ambiguous types such as `object` or `array` and instead describe how they are structured.
8. Due to the nature of redux and how you're setting your component up, you don't need to dispatch `setProfileLoading`. You can just update your data and the connected React component will update to reflect the new change. Dispatching two redux actions separately within a short period of time will most likely lead to component flashing (think of it as calling `this.setState()` twice within a second of each other -- it'll cause your component to flash).

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ovjq7k7516

**SelectOption.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Select from "react-select";
import { clearCurrentProfile, getCurrentProfile } from "../actions";

const options = [
  { value: "todos?userId=1", label: "Todos" },
  { value: "comments?postId=1", label: "Comments" },
  { value: "users?id=1", label: "Users" },
  { value: "albums?userId=1", label: "Albums" }
];

class SelectOption extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: []
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { getCurrentProfile, history } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state.selectedOption;

    this.setState({ selectedOption: [] }, () =>
      getCurrentProfile(value, history)
    );
  };

  handleChange = selectedOption => this.setState({ selectedOption });

  render = () => (
    <div className="container">
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Select
          value={this.state.selectedOption}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={options}
        />
        <div className="save-button">
          <button type="submit" className="uk-button uk-button-primary">
            Save Preferences
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="clear-button">
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={this.props.clearCurrentProfile}
            className="uk-button uk-button-danger"
          >
            Reset Preferences
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default connect(
  state => ({ profile: state.profile }),
  { clearCurrentProfile, getCurrentProfile }
)(withRouter(SelectOption));

SelectOption.propTypes = {
  clearCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  getCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  profile: PropTypes.shape({
    profile: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
    profiles: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
    loading: PropTypes.bool
  }).isRequired
};
```

**actions/index.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { GET_PROFILE, PROFILE_LOADING, CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE } from "../types";

//Get current profile
export const getCurrentProfile = (preference, history) => dispatch => {
  // dispatch(setProfileLoading()); // not needed 
  return axios
    .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${preference}`)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_PROFILE,
        payload: res.data
      });
      // history.push("/") // <== once data has been saved, push back to "/"
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_PROFILE,
        payload: { err }
      })
    );
};

//Get current profile (async/await)
// export const getCurrentProfile = (preference, history) => async dispatch => {
//   try {
//     dispatch(setProfileLoading()); // not needed

//     const res = await axios.get(
//       `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${preference}`
//     );

//     dispatch({
//       type: GET_PROFILE,
//       payload: res.data
//     });

//     // history.push("/") // <== once data has been saved, push back to "/"
//   } catch (e) {
//     dispatch({
//       type: GET_PROFILE,
//       payload: { e }
//     });
//   }
// };

//Profile Loading
export const setProfileLoading = () => ({ type: PROFILE_LOADING });
//Clear Profile
export const clearCurrentProfile = () => ({ type: CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE });
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE, GET_PROFILE, PROFILE_LOADING } from "../types";

const initialState = {
  profile: [],
  profiles: [],
  loading: false
};

const profileReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case PROFILE_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case GET_PROFILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: []
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default combineReducers({
  profile: profileReducer
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot kind sir

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Apparently, `React.StrictMode` was causing this issue. You can find React.StrictMode inside of `index.js`. Removing `React.StrictMode` solved the problem. However, I do not recommend it.

> StrictMode is a tool for highlighting potential problems in an application. Like Fragment, StrictMode does not render any visible UI. It activates additional checks and warnings for its descendants.
>
> StrictMode currently helps with:
>
> - Identifying componentd with unsafe lifecycles
> - Warning about legacy string ref API usage
> - Warning about deprecated findDOMNode usage
> - Detecting unexpected side effects
> - Detecting legacy context API
> - Ensuring reusable state

When you build the production version of your app the `React.StrictMode` will be automatically removed, so you do not need to remove it. You can read more about [React.StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) here!

Comment: You most likely need to use the cleanup function of useEffect. StrictMode mounts the component twice so you see exactly that bug (unsafe lifecycles).

Comment: You saved my Day - furkanayilmaz